# pass 1 environment variable using sudo

Tags: shell, sudo, environment-variables

Is this a correct way for passing an environment variable in sudo ?

```sh
sudo -u www-data -b env FOOBAR="foobar" /home/user/folder/daemon
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That works, but `env` isn't needed. You can run a test like this:

/tmp/test:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $tst
```

`chmod +x /tmp/test`

```
sudo tst=howdy /tmp/test
```

It's also possible to get environment variables through using the `-E` option, which preserves your environment (depending on other settings).