# Why isn't my environment variable visible from the command line?

Tags: osx, environment-variables, java

I'm trying to run the James SMTP server on Lion (Mac OS X 10.7.2).  When I do this:

```
sudo JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home ./james-2.3.2/bin/run.sh
```

it works fine.

However, I'd like to make JAVA_HOME an environment variable so it is visible to other applications too.

I edited ~/.bash_profile to look like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/home
```

and the variable appears to be visible from the command line like so:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/home
```

But when I run james again like this, I get a warning about JAVA_HOME:

```
$ sudo ./james-2.3.2/bin/run.sh
ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.

Please, set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Java Virtual Machine you want to use.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Why can't the command to run james see the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Any info is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "logout and login back to see changes"                                                if not try these Set JAVA_HOME as follows using syntax export JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java>. If your path is set to /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java, set it as follows:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java

Set PATH as follows:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin

Save and close the file. Just logout and login back to see new changes:
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
$ echo $PATH

Comment: [possible duplicate of many questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=sudo+environment), see especially [this answer by Gilles on the `-E`, preserve environment flag](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22853/11539).

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass 1 environment variable using sudo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/pass-1-environment-variable-using-sudo)

Answer (score 5):

`sudo` resets the environment variables to safe defaults.

If you want to preserve that variable, you need to `visudo` and add this:

```
Defaults env_keep = "JAVA_HOME"
```

Please note that carrying user environment variables over to privileged accounts is a possible security risk.

Comment: I'd say that this is the correct reason. But to carry over an environment variable from the user environment is a security hole.  I'd make sure to say that in your answer if you suggest editing the `sudoers` file.

Comment: Of course you are perfectly right. I edited the answer.

Comment: Maybe the question I should ask, then, is how should I run the james smtp as me instead of with sudo?  I'm running with sudo because james uses port 25 which I understand is not available to application that are not run by root.  Is that correct?  Any info is appreciated.

Comment: @Arcege Carrying environment variables over is only a security risk when you allow a user specific commands through sudo. If a user can run arbitrary commands through sudo, the erasure of environment variables is mostly a pointless annoyance.

Comment: @Gilles, with a wide open sudoers, that's true.  But it probably not a good practice to say "lets open up to allow a redirector EV like JAVA_HOME" as a general statement without mentioning that there are some _possible_ security risks.

Comment: @RobertHume It sounds like it should be started at boot time and let the appropriate services system ('service', 'rc', etc.) handle the startup and shutdown.  You probably should not be starting a network daemon like that out of your own account, but letting the OS start and stop it: `sudo service james restart`.  If James doesn't come with such a setup (if it is decent, then it should), then it's not hard to create a service/rc script.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether Lion has an `/etc` directory or not (I assume it does) or whether `/etc/bashprofile` or `/etc/bashrc` is actually in that directory, but if you want to make this change system-wide, just look for either of these files, edit it, and make the change there as so:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/Java/
```

Next log in will pick up the change and will be persisted.